# Ember: How to use the same template/route/controller for multiple API endpoints?

Tags: rest, ember.js, routes

I'll just explain simply what I want to do, and see what suggestions you have. I have a REST endpoint of api/articles that returns all articles (using Ember Data). Articles have authors, and suppose I have authored several articles and want to flip a switch in my template to see either all articles or just my articles.

Since the template should have exactly the same layout, how should my API and my router be set up to handle this kind of thing. Obviously, I would like to avoid having essentially duplicate "articles" and "myarticles" routes and endpoints for maintainability. I'm just not sure how to effectively switch endpoints, or if things should just be nested in some way to make this whole issue go away.

Comment: are you using Ember data?

Comment: yes, sorry, should have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query params to achieve this.

## 1

Lets assume your endpoint would be

```
/api/articles?author=all returns all articles
```

and

```
/api/articles?author=Mike returns articles of Mike.
```

In Route#model, you have to make a call to your end point based on query param.

Sample jsbin : http://jsbin.com/yijahe/1

## 2

In case your end point is not having querying features i.e, (end point would be /api/articles). Then do as suggested in Ember Doc http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/  i.e, get all articles in Route#model from end point, then you can filter articles based on the author name in Controller.

Sample jsbin: http://jsbin.com/hihexo

P.S: I did not use Ember model here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as the answer. It doesn't work for me I've found, because I'm using ember-cli-simple-auth, and I don't know how to intercept when it routes from the login page to my protected route.